# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

this is a simple program to check the database , sql queries are

```
    create database studentapp_db ;
    create table  students_info
    ( regno int(10) not null,
    firstname varchar (50) ,
    middlename varchar (50),
    lastname varchar (50),
    primary key(regno) ) ;
    insert into students_info
```

the error which i am getting while executing my java program are

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:0
 at  com.jspider.jdbc.common.callableStatementexample1.
 main(callableStatementexamp le1.java:32)
```

and here is  my java program

```
package com.jspider.jdbc.common;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;

public class callableStatementexample1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con = null;
        CallableStatement cstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            //1. load the driver

            Driver driverRef = new Driver();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(driverRef);

            //2. Get the Db conection 
            String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306  / Studentapp_db ? user = j2ee & password = j2ee ";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
            //3. Issue sql queries via connection

            //String query = "call getAllStudentsInfo()";
            String query = "call getAllStudentsInfo(4)";
            cstmt = con.prepareCall(query);
            cstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

            boolean isDBResults = cstmt.execute();

            //4 Process the results
            if (isDBResults) {
                System.out.println("Result is DB results");
                rs = cstmt.getResultSet();


                while (rs.next()) {
                    int regno = rs.getInt("regno");
                    String fNM = rs.getString("firstname");
                    String mNM = rs.getString("middlename");
                    String lNM = rs.getString("lastname");
                    System.out.println("Reg.No :" + regno);
                    System.out.println("First Name :" + fNM);
                    System.out.println("middle Name :" + mNM);
                    System.out.println("last Name :" + lNM);
                    System.out.println("-------------------");

                } //end of while 
            } else {
                System.out.println("Result is INT count");
                int Count = cstmt.getUpdateCount();
                System.out.println("Row affected Count" + Count);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            // 5. close all jdbc object
        } // end of outer try catch 
    }
}
```

the above  is  my java program , please help i am new to java  ;

EDIT:
The error occurs at the line of `cstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(args[0]));`, which is the 32th line.

Comment: Which line is `callableStatementexample1.java:32`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this(There is no argument in sql statement) call `getAllStudentsInfo(4)`to `call getAllStudentsInfo(?)` or Remove `cstmt.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(args[0]))`if you preferred hard coded value.

```
String query = "call getAllStudentsInfo(?)";
cstmt = con.prepareCall(query);
cstmt.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
```

Comment: thanx@Exbury , your suggestion helpd

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have started your program without parameter. So `args` has no objects.

You should check that before calling `Integer.parseInt(args[0])`;

Also your statement has no placeholder for your argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error, because of this line:

```
cstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(args[0]));
```

`args` is the array representing the command-line arguments passed when you ran the program. Since you did not pass any command-line arguments, there is no 0th element of `args`.

Solution: pass an integer value as command-line argument when you run the program.